# Send custom dimension value to Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics Android SDK v3 and the EasyTracker. I wan't to send a value to Google with a custom dimension. I created the dimension already in the webinterface and put the code in to send the value, but it doesn't show.

I would like to know, if my code is right, or what I have done wrong.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);

    if (boolean){ 
        String cookie = getCookie(URL, cookie_name);                

        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).send(MapBuilder
            .createAppView()
            .set(Fields.customDimension(1), cookie)
            .build()
        );
    }
}
```

Another attempt was this, but it didn't work neither.

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).set(Fields.customDimension(1), cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to setup the dimension at google analytics:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en